# Exact value of a root on Python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm writing a programme that converts complex numbers.
Right now I'm having problems with this piece of code:

```
import numpy

complexnr = 1+1j
mod= numpy.absolute(complexnr)
print(mod)
```

The output of this code is:

```
1.4142135623730951
```

I would like to get √2 as the output.

I have been advised to use the sympy module but I have had no luck with this either. What would be the easiest way to get this result?

EDIT

```
input_list = ["Enter your complex number (a+bi): ", \
                      "Degrees or radians?", \
                      "To how many decimal places do you want to round the argument?"]
        output = multenterbox(text, title, input_list)

        algebraline = output[0]
        choice = output[1]
        round2 = int(output[2])
        
        #converting complex number to a suitable form for numpy
        if "i" in algebraline:
            j = algebraline.replace("i","j")
            indeks = algebraline.index("i")
            list = []
            for element in algebraline:
                list.append(element)
            if "i" in algebraline and algebraline[indeks-1]=="+" or algebraline[indeks-1]=="-":
                list.insert(indeks, 1)
                x = "".join(str(e) for e in list)
                j = x.replace("i","j")
            arv = eval(j)
        elif "i" not in algebraline:
            arv = eval(algebraline)

        #let's find the module
        a = int(list[0])
        b = int(list[2])
        module = sqrt(a**2+b**2)
```

this method works well when the complex number is 1+i for example, however when i try to insert sqrt(3)-1i, the list looks like this ['s', 'q', 'r', 't', '(', '3', ')', '-', 1, 'i'] and my programme won't work. Same problem occurs when b is a root (for example 1-sqrt(3)i). What can be done to make it work for square roots as well? (I need numpy later on to calculate angles, that's why converting 'i' into 'j' is important)

Comment: What have you tried with sympy?

Comment: If you literally need the output √2, why not write that as a string? What operations other than printing as √2 must the result be capable of?

Comment: I would do it my self, but then use a library to simplify. It this case the simplification will do nothing. But, for the case `2+2i`, I would calculate `√(2²+2²)=√8`, that would simplify to `2√2`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What!! I am assuming that the OP has written a minimal program that exhibits the problem. Not the most complex program to print √2.

Comment: Also, what would be the limit of your expectations? Only write as square roots the roots of integers? What about sqrt(2)/2? Values that can be represented exactly as sums of square roots of integers? ...

Answer (score 1):

Works by using

- I (from sympy) rather than 1j
- builtin abs function which calls sympby.Abs for complex arguments

**Code**

```
from sympy import I

complexnr = 1 + I       # use I rather than 1j
display(abs(complexnr))   # also works with np.abs and np.absolute
```

Output: [image]

```
 print(abs(complexnr))
```

Output: sqrt(2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SymPy, you have to write the complex numbers as sympy expressions.

```
from sympy import *
cabs = lambda z: sqrt(re(z)**2 + im(z)**2)
complexnr = 1 + 1j
print(cabs(complexnr))
# out: 1.4142135623731
```

We are getting a float number because `complexnr` is of type `complex` and its real and imaginary parts are of type `float`. Thus, SymPy's `re` and `im` functions returns float numbers. But when `sqrt` receives a float number, it evaluates the result.

We can workaround this problem in two ways.

The first: if we are dealing with simple complex numbers where real and imaginary parts are integers, we can write the complex number as a string, `sympify` it (which means convert to a sympy expression):

```
complexnr = sympify("1 + 1j")
print(cabs(complexnr))
# out: sqrt(2)
```

A second way consist in using the complex number directly, then apply `nsimplify` in order to attempt to convert the resulting float number to some symbolic form:

```
complexnr = 1 + 1j
result = cabs(complexnr) # result is a Float number, 1.4142135623731
print(result.nsimplify())
# out: sqrt(2)
```